llama_index version "^0.10.44" get ERROR when importing LLMPredictor and LlamaLogger
I upgrade llama_index version from 0.6.0 to 0.10 but this raise error related to import LLMPredictor and LlamaLogger. I take google search but not found result
Ho do I fix this issue?
Import LLMPredictor and LlamaLogger is success

LLMPredictor seems to be deprecated (source)
LlamaLogger seems to be included only in the legacy code base (source)
You can use them using the legacy approach (docs here), but that would only be a temporary solution.
